# count up towards and printing an entered integer number in binary

Tags: c, recursion, binary

I am trying to print out binary of an entered integer number counting up from 0 (eg. 0,1,10,11,100... to the entered number)  I have most of the coding done I'm just struggling with the two recursive calls in my print Binary code: it prints out each digit at a time a 1 or a 0 until it needs to go to the next line. I was wondering if anyone could look at my code and inform me on what I should be doing? 
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int biggestPower2(int);

void printBinary(int, int);

int main()
{
    int i;
    int input;
    printf("Enter the number to count up to: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    for (i = 0; i<=input; i++)
    {

        printBinary(i, biggestPower2(i));
    }
}

int biggestPower2(int decimal)
{
    if ((decimal == 0)||(decimal == 1))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 2*biggestPower2(decimal/2);
    }
}

void printBinary(int decimal, int power2)
{
    int nextDigit;
    if (power2 == 1)
    {
        printf("%d\n", decimal);
    }
    else
    {
        nextDigit = decimal/power2;
        printf("%d", nextDigit);
        if (nextDigit == 1)
        {
            printBinary(decimal%2, power2/2);
        }
        else
        {
            printBinary((decimal)%2, power2/1);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You get into an infinite recursion. Use a debugger and execute your program step by step and you will see why.

Comment: BTW there is no reason for using recursion here.

Comment: It isn't infinite recursion the numbers just don't come out right (unless I made a mistake copying it over to this), also I know it doesn't need to be but its what my course is requiring of me

Comment: Actually you are right, it's not infinite recursion. The whole algorithm is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct representation of your `printBinary` function should be as follows:

```
printBinary(a,b) = if(b==1) print a
                   if(a>b) print "1" 
                   else print "0"
                   printBinary(a%b, b/2)

where the initial b is largest power of 2 less than equal to a.
```

You start with the highest power less than the given number. If it is less than the current number, then the bit is set, or else not. Then you call the same function with the remainder `a%b` and next power `b/2`.

The modified code should be as follows:

```
void printBinary(int decimal, int power2)
{
  if (power2 == 1)
  {
      printf("%d\n", decimal);
      return;
  }
  printf("%d", decimal/power2);
  printBinary(decimal%power2, power2/2);
}
```

And btw to find the largest power of `2` less than or equal to `n`, you can simply do:

```
 long int largest_powr_less_than_n = pow(2.0,floor(log(n)/log(2)))
```

instead of writing a separate(that too recursive!) function.

**EDIT:**

A more simpler recursive implementation looks as follows:

```
void printBinary(int decimal)
{
    if(decimal<=1)
      printf("%d", decimal);
    else
    {
      printBinary(decimal/2);
      printf("%d", decimal&1);
    }
}
```

I leave it to you on how the above function works.

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler:

```
void printBinary(int decimal, int power2)
{
  int nextDigit;
  if (power2 == 1)
  {
      printf("%d\n", decimal);
  }
  else
  {
      nextDigit = decimal/power2;
      printf("%d", nextDigit);
      printBinary(decimal%power2, power2/2);
  }
}
```